# Foxit webpage embeded view - Hide toolbar

Tags: html, foxit

I have an embedded pdf in my mvc web application. I am currently trying to hide the toolbar for both foxit pdf reader. How can I go about doing this? I've tried the below and it is not working?

```
<object data="@Url.Action("GetPDF", new { BookType = ViewBag.BookType, Book = ViewBag.Book, StartPage = ViewBag.StartPage })#view=Fitp&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" style="width:100%; height:700px;">
   <param name="toolbar" value="0" />
   <param name="height" value="20px" />
   <param name="view" value="Fitp" />
   <param name="SRC" value="#view=Fitp&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using Foxit technology to embed a PDF viewer in your web page you might be interested in looking at Foxit WebPDF.js -- it is free. It's based on the same core technology as Foxit Reader but is provided as a JavaScript lib with a HTML/CSS/JS viewer included in the download package.

https://github.com/foxitsoftware/WebPDF.js